# Add lines at end of csv

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have csv file with 100 rows and only one column. I need to add 100 rows of commas at the end of it. How do I do it?

Comment: 100 lines of commas? Du you mean 100 lines with a single comma on each?

Comment: Yes. I need 100 rows of just commas at the end of 100 already existing rows

Answer (score 1):

To add 100 lines, each with a single comma, to the end of the file `data`:

```
yes , | head -n 100 >>data
```

The `yes` utility will usually output the letter `y` infinitely, but with `yes ,` we change the `y` to a comma.  We take the 100 first commas and append these to the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf '%.s,\n' {1..100} >>file
```